# Parent vue missing events fired by child

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

[Code Here](https://github.com/write-io/write.io/tree/single-file-components) + [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ripper234/w7ofx28n/)

I'm trying to communicate data from a child vue to parent vue.

The parent `app.vue` registers on events:

```
created: function () {
  this.$on('nickname-selected', function (params) {
    console.log('nickname-selected event fired, params= ' + params)
  })
  console.log('app.vue registered on nickname-selected events')
}
```

The child `home.vue` fires an event

```
login: function () {
  ...
  this.$emit('nickname-selected', this.nickname)
  console.log('home emitted nickname-selected event')
```

But the event isn't picked up by the parent.

```
app.vue registered on nickname-selected events
home emitted nickname-selected event
```

Comment: You are adding the event listener to the wrong component.  The event is on home.vue.

Comment: @djones how come. I'd like the parent (app) to listen to events from the child (home) ... (and then in phase 2 update the global data with the new nickname)

Comment: Asked on gitter, I got the recommendation to just start a new project using vue-cli. https://gitter.im/vuejs/vue?at=588821fa074f7be7631437d5

Comment: You need to attach the listener to the child component.  So `child.$on()` or use the `v-on` directive.

Comment: Personally, I would prefer having `methods` in parent and passing them down to the child. Especially in the case of parent-child communication.